# Keycloak - I want a required social login appears after username/password login

Tags: keycloak

We need that the user has a social login, but initially, if we wants to, he can login with username/password.

so the flow would be something like:
if he logins using social(google or apple) is done.
if he logins using username and password, we want to ask him a social login too.

is that possible using keycloak?
how can i do it?